# PHP Email form not sending textarea

Tags: php, email

I've got a simple email form in PHP that is to send a form input to the email address. However, the textarea isn't included. The phone number is being sent, just the textarea is not. Here's my form:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="send.php">
<p>  <span id="sprytextfield1">Your name:
  <label for="name"></label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></p>
  <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span>
  <p><span id="sprytextfield2">
    <label for="email">Email address:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
    <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></p>
  <p>
    <label for="phone">Phone Number:</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" />
  </p>

  <p><span id="sprytextarea1">
    <label for="message">Message</label>
    <br />
    <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
  <span class="textareaRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" />
    <br />
  </p>
</form>
```

After that, I have the validation for the form.
Here's the php

```
$name=$_POST[name];
$email=$_POST[email];
$phone=$_POST[phone];
$message=$_POST[message];

$from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email"; 
       $subject="Message sent using your contact form"; 
      mail("my@email.com", $subject, $from, $phone, $message); 
    echo "Email sent!";
```

Answer (score 2):

change your

```
$name=$_POST[name];
$email=$_POST[email];
$phone=$_POST[phone];
$message=$_POST[message];
```

to

```
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$message=$_POST['message'];
```

your message will work with this way

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, you aren't using parameters in the correct order. As per mail documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php), it should be:

```
mail("my@email.com", $subject, $message, $from);
```

I am not sure where you want to use `$phone` but may be you can concatenate it to `$message` before sending it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked, for some reason. Using $subject, $message, $from would only send the message. I got rid of the phone number.

```
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$message=$_POST['message'];

  $from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email"; 
        $subject="Someone from your website is contacting you"; 
        mail("me@email.com", $subject, $from, $message); //weird, but it works
```